# How to proper positioning elements in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to have in listview in listitem (*Note: the listitem `<li>` is generated dynamically with JS*) **product value** on the left and **button** on the right but
I have `align="center"` in `<div data-role="main" align="center">`
and get centered **product value** and **button** but if I place in `<div>` (in listitem) **product value**  and in another `<div>` a **button**
I get on the left **product value** and on the right button (but in lower line)
like this img [image]
so how to proper position this?

```
var li = '<li><div>' + productVal + btn + '</div></li>';
```

so on the left sth and on the right a button
here is my code https://jsbin.com/revuto/edit?html,output

actually I have [image]
but want [image]

sorry for Polish text in code
so I translate Polish - English

Wprowadź product - provide a product

dodaj - add

usuń- remove

niebezpieczna strefa- danger zone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a wrapper classed `ui-grid-a` and wrap each "column" in a div `ui-block-a` and `ui-block-b`

e.g.

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <label class="ui-block-a" for="input">
        label: <input type="text" id="input">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <br>
        <button type="button" >Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I meant not <input type="text"> with data-clear-btn="true" but this input as a model only position of elements sth on the left and sth another on the right but grid this is a probably solution thx 
so grid like a bootstrap's grid